# Recursive static member functions Vs ordinary member functions

Tags: c++, class, recursion, static, member-functions

Is it true that recursive functions are faster when the functions are declared as static member functions (instead of ordinary member functions). For example something like this:

```
class Tree {
  Node* p;
public:
  static int height(Node* n){
     .......
     int lh = height(n->left);
     int rh = height(n->right);
     ......
  }
};
```

What could be the possible reason for this?

Comment: The best way to learn about things like this is to first write a test for yourself and see.

Comment: You will really have to show us what your alternative code is. But it's unlikely that it makes a huge difference in a modern compiler...

Comment: I am not really concerned about the difference in speed, but I just want to know the possible reason why this happens.

Comment: Consider also: `int height() const { return p->height(); }` and have `height` as a (recursive) member function of `Node`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a technical sense this is true (or at least it *may* be true*) because every nonstatic member function call includes an invisible `this` parameter. For example, if the `height` function in your example were nonstatic, its effective signature would be `int height(Tree* this, Node* n)`. So if you don't need `this`, you do waste some nonzero number of cycles passing it.

However, in practice it's very unlikely to matter (depending on exactly what you're doing, of course). So write the code however it makes the most sense, and only worry about making micro-optimizations if the profiler shows that (a) you have a problem and (b) the optimization makes a difference.

*I say *may* be true because I suspect most compilers will just optimize away the unused parameter anyway, but I'm not 100% certain of that.

Comment: It'll be optimized out if inlined, but not optimized out if not inlined (unless the compiler is capable of doing IPO). The reason is simple: at the call site, the compiler doesn't know whether or not the function needs the `this` pointer. Best way to analyze these types of things is to simply look at the assembly language output.

Comment: @user3521733 But... but it's Friday night and... aw; who am I kidding. I did the experiment with VS2013 and in release mode with inlining suppressed, it generated the exact same assembly code with and without `static`. For a debug build, omitting `static` resulted in an extra `lea` instruction at the call site, as one would expect. All code was in a single cpp file, which might make have been what allowed the optimization.

Comment: For fun, because we have nothing better to do, if you post your code in some way I'll compile it with g++ and clang++.

Comment: Actually, now that I think about it, it shouldn't matter whether or not the object had data members, since inside the function it could refer to `this`. So I suspect it was doing some IPO.

Comment: @user3521733 This is going to look hideous in comment form, but it was just this: `#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class C
{
public:
 int a;

 /* static */ void f();
};

void C::f()
{
 int c = 0;
 std::cin >> c;
}

int main()
{
 C c;
 c.f();
}`

Comment: Well, unfortunately it seems that I can't get either g++ or clang++ to optimize but not inline. (I tried `-O -fno-inline` but no dice.) So they both had the extra instruction for the member function.

Comment: @user maybe if you take the address of f? But I suppose that might prevent changing the Sig too...

Comment: I moved the implementation to a separate file to prevent inlining. So now I do get the extra store regardless of whether or not `-O` is used. Unfortunately, hard to post code in a comment. clang++ had `leaq (%rsp), %rdi callq   _ZN1C1fEv`. g++ had `movq    %rsp, %rdi
call    _ZN1C1fEv`.

Comment: Note that this is assuming that the function belongs there and that the arguments are the same (except the implicit `this`). If the code is changed to: `int lh = left->height();` (vs. `int lh = this->height(n->node);`) then the arguments to the function are exactly the same, a `Node*`, call it `this` (member of `Node`) or `n` (static function in `Tree`).